# can we specify x.csv file path when we create hive external table?

Tags: hive, hiveql

Based on the syntax of creating external table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE page_view(viewTime INT, userid BIGINT, 
    page_url STRING, referrer_url STRING, 
    ip STRING COMMENT 'IP Address of the User',
    country STRING COMMENT 'country of origination')
 COMMENT 'This is the staging page view table'
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\054'
 STORED AS TEXTFILE
 LOCATION '<hdfs_location>';
```

At LOCATION, is that true we can only specify the path of the directory where the target csv file is located? Could we also specify directly the path of the csv file? We might meet the situation that multiple csv files located in one folder.

Answer (score 0):

You only designate the path. Multiple files are unioned together when you query the external table, so as long as the structures are the same then there are no issues. Files of different structures should be stored in different directories.